# Python - extract only first numbers

Tags: python

I have a column with object `dtype`, where numbers, text and symbols are all mixed up.

For example:

```
0 200 lbs today (189 last year)

1 99 lbs

2 250 lbs with clothes on (247 without)

3 current weight is 330
```

I need to extract only numbers, but I've been trying for hours without success.

I've tried with `to_numeric` like this:

```
raw['weight'] = pd.to_numeric(raw['weight'], errors='coerce', downcast='integer')
```

Given it's an object dtype`, many parsing errors arise, but when I use coerce, the entire column becomes`NaN`.

Any ideas?

The expected output would show all first numbers. The result from my example would be: 200, 99, 250, 300

Comment: Have you tried to use a regex?

Comment: [Get numbers from string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-all-the-numbers-in-a-string-using-regular-expression-in-python/) using Regex

Comment: I tried with findall and search with no success. I get the "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: Do you want all or just some of the numbers?  For instance, some lines have multiple weights--do you want both.  Also, do you want the line numbers?  Perhaps you can show what the desired output should look like.

Comment: Right. The data is a mess... I need the first numbers (can be 2, 3 digits). The output of my example would be: 200, 99, 250, 330

Comment: Use a regex. Do you want the first, last or all occurrences of numbers? e.g. for `200 lbs today (189 last year)` do you want to return `200` or `[200, 189]`? You should show us your expected output.

Comment: @smci just did that in the previous comment. It's on the main post now.

Comment: Ok then you want to "extract only first number", not all numbers. And I wouldn't  put "assign NaN value" in the title; you only mean how do you handle `pd.to_numeric(..., errors='coerce'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
import re

raw['weight'] = raw.Weight.apply(lambda x: re.search('[-+]?[0-9]+', x).group(0))
```

This would grab the first number found in the string. You would have to modify to get only the one in parenthesis, outside of parenthesis, etc.

[EDIT]

If NaN values are present in the `Weight` column the above example will fail. If you don't want to drop the NaN values you could handle them with something like this:

```
import re

def get_num(val):
    if not isinstance(val, str):
        return val
    else:
        return re.search('[-+]?[0-9]+', val).group(0)

raw['weight'] = raw.Weight.apply(lambda x: get_num(x))
```

Comment: I get the "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object". Not sure why.

Comment: I copied your example data above and it worked fine on my box..You probably have NaN values in the column which is why it is throwing the error. If you don't want to drop them you will need a sub function to handle that case.

Comment: Edited to include case where the column is mixed type. Just an example, but I would use regrex if the value is a string and if it is not a string you can replace with NaN or whatever you want. the above is just returning whatever was originally in the column if not a string.

Comment: Exactly. Lots of NaN values. I don't care about those. Should I just drop them and use your lines?

Comment: Whatever makes sense for your use case. Are the other columns in your DataFrame important even if NaN is in the weight column? If so don't drop them otherwise dropping them makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, the other columns are important regardless of NaNs in the weight column. Starting to make sense of it. Thanks for the time.

Comment: Then use something like the second block after the edit. No problem, good luck.

Comment: With your most recent suggestion, I get the "TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types"  I'll get there, grrrrr

Comment: Did you copy exactly? `if not isinstance(val, str):` The error implies you didn't pass a type. `str` is a type, so that error should not occur if it is typed as shown above.

Comment: Yeah, I copied exactly. Don't get it. As you say, str should count as type in arg 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205119/discussion-between-denver-and-micaela-de-leon).

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to find digits inside strings, then do what you need with the result.

```
import re
strings=("0 200 lbs today (189 last year)","1 99 lbs","2 250 lbs with clothes on (247 without)","3 current weight is 330")
numbers=[]
for item in strings:
    numbers.append(re.findall('[0-9]+',item))
print (numbers)
```

Comment: I get the "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object". The thing is... the column where I want to extract the numbers from, has like 500 items and is part of a df. ;aybe I'm doing something wrong. I´ll keep trying, if any more ideas come up, let me know!

Comment: Maybe convert everything to string using str() right after you grabbed it from your source and then pass it to regex?